# EF Core Dependents not deleted when severed from parent in optional relationship even with Delete Behavior Configured

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have my entities configured for optional one to many relationship using `PropertyAccessMode.Field` mode to make things happen in `DDD` way. I'm loading parent entity along with two child. Now I'm removing one child from parent and save it. To my surprise, I can see EF setting `NULL` in child table column for foreign key. I then searched through docs and found in this section [Optional relationship with dependents/children loaded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete#optional-relationship-with-dependentschildren-loaded) that Delete Behavior needs to be set so that dependents will be deleted by EF Core on severe but still EF Core is not deleting the child instead it sets `NULL` in foreign key field.

[image]

This issue happens only with optional relationship. If I make the below code to have required relationship EF is deleting the child as expected with the same code. Just that I need to mark relationship as required and do changes in table to make Foreign Key column as `NOT NULL`.

[image]

**EF Core Details:**

EF Core version: 7.0.3

Database provider: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

Target framework: .NET 6.0

**Code Sample:**

```
using (var context = new EFDbContext())
{
    var orderItems = new List<OrderItem> { new OrderItem ("one"), new OrderItem ("two") };
    var order = new Order("Test", orderItems);
    context.Orders.Add(order);
    context.SaveChanges();
}

using (var context = new EFDbContext())
{
    var order = context.Orders.Include(x => x.OrderItems).FirstOrDefault();
    order.RemoveOrderItem(order.OrderItems[0]);
    context.Orders.Update(order);
    context.SaveChanges();
}

public class EFDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Test;User Id=sa;Password=xxxx;TrustServerCertificate=true");
        optionsBuilder.LogTo(Console.WriteLine);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("Order");
            entity.HasKey(x => x.Id);

            entity.HasMany(order => order.OrderItems)
                   .WithOne()
                   .IsRequired(false)
                   .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade)
                   .Metadata.PrincipalToDependent.SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<OrderItem>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("OrderItem");
            entity.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        });
    }
}

public class Order
{
    private readonly List<OrderItem> _orderItems = new();

    private Order() { }

    public Order(string name, List<OrderItem> orderItems)
    {
        Name = name;
        _orderItems = orderItems;
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IReadOnlyList<OrderItem> OrderItems => _orderItems.ToList();

    public void RemoveOrderItem(OrderItem orderItem)
    {
        _orderItems.Remove(orderItem);
    }
}

public class OrderItem
{
    private OrderItem() { }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public OrderItem(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Please assist me if I'm missing something.

Comment: Your `RemoveOrderItem` method should not exist. Remove it. Instead use `DbSet.Remove`. The reason for this is because your `RemoveOrderItem` method has no way of changing its `OrderItem` argument's `EntityState.Deleted` state in its owner `DbContext`. EF does not use member collections to determine if a previously-loaded entity is now detached or deleted, it only uses the `DbContext`'s internal state manager. (Also, your `RemoveOrderItem` method has no way of knowing if the `orderItem` argument is even a member of the same owner `DbContext` or not.

Comment: Since I'm using `DDD`, I cannot allow `child` entities to be directly operated via `DbSet.Remove`. I'm trying to do it via `aggregate` or `parent`. EF Core should be aware of the `EntityState` even if I use `RemoveOrderItem` because my entities are tracked. The same setup works in case of required relationship but not with optional relationship.

Comment: By "DDD" do you mean "domain-driven design"? If so, I don't see how that's relevant - because using any ORM necessarily means compromising your design to match the ORM's requirements. ORMs aren't magic, and even if they were actually magic then that would be a very strong reason to avoid using it because magic side-effects in software are demonstrably a bad design.

Comment: _"EF Core should be aware of the EntityState even if I use RemoveOrderItem because my entities are tracked."_ - I think you're grossly overstating how omniscient EF's entity-tracking abilities are (because they aren't).

Comment: No no!! the development is DDD way. And I'm trying to configure ORM to fit my domain design. And regarding tracking, I wonder how it works when relationship is not optional. Hence said so...

Comment: _"And I'm trying to configure ORM to fit my domain design."_ - you can't. EFCore doesn't work like that.

Comment: @Dai according to the documentation referenced (and highlighted) it is stated that EF Core does exactly what OP expects. Please point to some documentation saying otherwise. Btw. I have the exact same issue although not using DDD so I can actually access the DbContext - I would just very much prefer not needing to traverse the object graph to manually remove all objects in a hierarchy

Comment: @fingers10 DDD has nothing to do with how ORMs work and your ORM DTOs are *not* your Domain entities. You can use the same type for both only if you don't interfere with the ORM's behavior. Not the other way around. That said, EF Core and NHibernate are such high-level ORMs that they completely eliminate the need for single-entity repositories and custom units of work. Queries return the entire object graph at once, so there's no need for CRUD classes. A DbContext instance *is* a unit of work already, so all you need to implement UoW is a `using` block and, if you use DI, scoped services

Comment: As for your question - the model doesn't specify that OrderItem is *owned* by Order. `context.Orders.Update(order);` is meaningless as the DbContext already tracks both the Order and its OrderItems. `Update` is *only* needed to attach a detached object in the Modified or Added state. You can specify ownership by specifying a [collection of owned types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#collections-of-owned-types)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the same question asked (and answered) on [Github](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/30752) by the EF Core team. It's because from EF Core 7.0 onwards, orphaned dependents of optional relationships are no longer deleted by default according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/breaking-changes?tabs=v7#optional-deletes